# Calling a parameterized Stored Procedure that returns a value in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

C# --> I have a parameterized stored procedure (SP) that returns an int that I want to call and read the return value that I want to assign to a hidden field.  I believe I have most of it written but am stuck on the final part (actually extracting the returned value from the SP.  Help would be much appreciated.  Here is what I have so far...

```
public int CheckIP()
{
    string conn = "";
    conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ToString();
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
    try
    {
        sqlconn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CheckIP", sqlconn);
        objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter IPAddress = objcmd.Parameters.Add("@IpAddress",
            SqlDbType.VarChar);
        IPAddress.Value = 0;

        SqlDataAdapter objAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(objcmd);
        objAdp.Fill(ds);

        ????
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlconn.Close();
    }
}
```

And my Stored Procedure is as follows:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_CheckIP]
@IpAddress varchar(15),
@AllowedLogInAttempts int Output

AS
BEGIN

IF (Select Count(IPAddressID) From Emerald.dbo.IPManager 
    Where IPAddress = @IPAddress) = 1
BEGIN

Select @AllowedLogInAttempts = 
     CASE
        When Trusted = 0 and Block = 0 then '5'
        When Trusted = 1 and Block = 0 then '7'
        When Trusted = 0 and Block = 1 then '0'
        When Trusted = 1 and Block = 1 then '0'
        End 
FROM Emerald.dbo.IPManager
Where IPAddress = @IPAddress

END
ELSE 
Select 3
END
```

Comment: Regarding your SP: The `CASE` result is a string, but the output variable is an `INT`. Using `EXISTS` rather than `COUNT` may be more appropriate. You can `SELECT` the desired row and, if the result is NULL, substitute your default value (`3`) rather than performing two `SELECT`s on the table.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your code as follows change I have made is I have added return variable for SP and that will return output value.

```
public int CheckIP()
{
 string conn = "";
 conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ToString();
 SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
 try
 {
     sqlconn.Open();
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CheckIP", sqlconn);
     objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     SqlParameter IPAddress = objcmd.Parameters.Add("@IpAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar);
     IPAddress.Value = 0;


     SqlParameter returnParameter = new SqlParameter("@AllowedLogInAttempts", SqlDbType.Int);
     returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
     objcmd.Parameters.Add(returnParameter);

      objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     int id = (int) returnParameter.Value;    

     //Now here write your logic to assign value hidden field
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
 }
 finally
 {
     sqlconn.Close();
 }
}
```

Comment: I made the suggested changes, however I'm getting the following error: Procedure or function 'CheckIP' expects parameter '@AllowedLogInAttempts', which was not supplied.

Comment: objcmd.Parameters.Add("@AllowedLogInAttempts", Removed space in this stament after @AllowedLogInAttempts. Try it now.

Comment: I have made some chnages try updated code now. But in fact we are proving the '@AllowedLogInAttempts' it is strange that we are getting same error. Still give it try with updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

retval = objcmd.ExecuteScalar();

Answer (score 0):

```
Select @AllowedLogInAttempts = 
     CASE
        When Trusted = 0 and Block = 0 then '5'
        When Trusted = 1 and Block = 0 then '7'
        When Trusted = 0 and Block = 1 then '0'
        When Trusted = 1 and Block = 1 then '0'
     End 
FROM Emerald.dbo.IPManager
Where IPAddress = @IPAddress
```

Could be shortened to:

```
Select @AllowedLogInAttempts = (Trusted * 2 + 5) * (Block ^ 1)
```

Comment: I like it!...Can you explain the syntax on the above?  It works but the syntax doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Block ^ 1 is "Block XOR 1" so if Block is 1, returns 0. If Block is 0, returns 1. I'd just throw the rest in a truth table for validation...